# Association won't save inside of before_validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to use the before_validation callback to adjust the number of child objects for a record, but for some reason, its not working the way I expect.

LineItem class:

```
 before_validation :adjust_enrollment_count

 def adjust_enrollment_count
    if enrollments.size < quantity 
      (enrollments.size+1..quantity).each do |li|
        self.enrollments.build(variant: self.variant)
      end
      #self.save
    elsif enrollments.size > quantity
      enrollments.delete_if do |e| 
        enrollments.size > quantity
      end
    end
  end
```

What happens is that it creates the correct number of Enrollment objects as children to the LineItem, but the Variant gets set to nil (even though the LineItem has a variant defined).

Things I've tried:

- Explicitly saving the line_item or the enrollment
- "pry"ing into the callback and running the code manually (this actually worked the way
  I expected!)
- Verifying that "self" referred to the LineItem and not the closure

Is there something about the callback lifecycle that I'm missing? Is there a better way to adjust the number of Enrollment objects as the quantity changes on the LineItem?

Comment: What type of field is 'variant'? Is it a string or integer field in LineItem, or is it another model so it's working as a foreign key reference? Also, is there any special reason you want to do this in before_validation instead of in an after_save callback?

Comment: @sockmonk - I figured it out (see my answer below). But Variant was another model.  I tried after_save and for some reason the callback was never called. I didn't investigate to much further before I tried before_validation and encountered this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `variant` is not an accessible field of the `Enrollment` class. Try this way (also shortened)

```
def adjust_enrollment_count
  while enrollments.size < quantity 
    self.enrollments.build(variant_id: self.variant) # note: variant_id
  end
  while enrollments.size > quantity
    enrollments.pop # or .shift to delete from the head of the list
  end
  # don't save in a lifecycle callback, or you'll get in an awful loop
end
```

**EDIT: a different take**

```
def add_enrollment
  enrollments.build(variant_id: variant)
end

def adjust_enrollment_count
  enrollments.slice!(quantity, enrollments.size)
  add_enrollment while enrollments.length < quantity
end
```

Comment: This didn't necessarily solve the problem, but it is a much simpler way to write the code, so thanks!

Comment: Oh, and I definitely experienced the endless loop, that's why I had it commented out. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the problem was something that I didn't have outlined in my question. I had defined the following:

```
class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :line_item

  attr_accessible :variant
  attr_accessor   :variant
end
```

I think the attr_accessor was creating an in-memory variable called variant that only lasted as long as the page load. I removed that and it seemed to solve the problem.

Comment: I already stated it in the first line of my answer. A problem with the accessibility of the variable. ActiveRecord accessible fields have nothing to do with instance variables, nor with accessors to them. an `attr_accessor` statement creates getters and setters over a `@variant` instance var. This overrides activerecord's attribute accessors.

Comment: (and using `variant_id` in the build method should have overcome the problem...)

Comment: variant_id didn't overcome the problem, but you're right, it was an accessibility issue, so I'll accept your answer.